# Jacobian matrix cutoff in ODE solver

Tags: matrix, ode, runge-kutta, jacobian

I am studying an implementation of a 3rd semi-implicit Runge Kutta method (siRK3) from the book by Villadsen & Michelsen (1978), *Solution of differential equation models by polynomial approximation*, Prentice-Hall.

The code expects an analytically evaluated Jacobian matrix $J = \partial F / \partial y$. In the calculation of the new function values $y^{n+1}(t + h)$, the matrix $I -h a J$ is assembled by overwriting the storage used by the Jacobian matrix (array `df`):

```
    do i = 1, n
      do j = 1, n
        df(i,j) = -h * a * df(i,j)
        if (abs(df(i,j)) < DF_TOL) df(i,j) = 0.0_dp
      end do
      df(i,i) = df(i,i) + 1.0_dp
    end do
```

In the original code, `DF_TOL = 1.0d-12`. Afterwards an LU factorization of the matrix `df` is performed and used to calculate the new function values by back-substitution.

What is the purpose of truncating the Jacobian matrix values, and why choose this particular cutoff value? Is this type of truncation needed at all?

Comment: I think it is to prevent false non-zeros (which may occur due to floating point arithmetic), but it should be considered in a relative sense. If all the jacobian entries are small (<1e-12) then it does not make sense to compare to 1e-12; it should be replaced by 1e-12*max(abs(df)).

Comment: The value 1e-12 still feels a bit arbitrary. Shouldn't it change with the target precision (i.e. single vs double), or be left as an optional user input? If it is known all entries are small, wouldn't good modelling practice require the original problem should be non-dimensionalized/scaled.

Comment: You are right, but remember that the book was published in 1978. The double precision standard was not readily available back then (officially adopted in 1985, even though there were some vendors offering it earlier and not fully adopted until a few years later), so the arbitrary (I agree with you on that point) tolerance 1e-12 is for single precision. Also, the book is on the solution of ODEs, so probably they did not care much about the intricacies of the floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Good point. It would be nice to learn if any modern ODE libraries use this type of cutoff or is this an outdated practice that I can simply remove in the refactored code.

Comment: It's not just an outdated practice, but you do not see this in any of the major classic ODE solvers (Shampine, Hairer, Hindmarsh). And modern ODE solvers like those in Julia don't do this because automatic differentiation removes floating point errors of finite differencing. So really this looks to be the quirk of one person's not widely tested implementation.

Comment: Besides, it doesn't even make sense in modern SDIRK/IMEX codes because that change would be below the error of modern Jacobian reuse schema. If I had to guess the reason for it, it may  have been some trick to try and avoid floating point error growth when using LU-factorizations without pivoting, but if you just use a standard BLAS routine this would make essentially no difference.

Comment: I agree it looks quirky. It might have been a trick to avoid round-off problems on some legacy processor, before the IEEE standards were introduced. Would you like to expand your comment into an answer? Concerning the autodiff Jacobians, I believe you meant it removes the truncation errors. "Floating point" errors can be understood as a combination of representation error and round-off error, both of which are still present even in autodiff.